# Calculating a factorial

Tags: java, android

I am developing a calculator application in Android.

I have developed the calculator and is working well except for the factorial function.

The function to calculate factorial is:

```
public float factorial (float n){
    float ans=1;
    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++){
        ans=ans*i;
    }
    return ans;
}
```

The problem is that until `34!` I think I get correct answer.

```
34!=2.952328229965333E38
```

However for `n>=35`, I get the answer

```
n!=Infinity
```

I realize that this is because of float overflow.
How can I increase the range of the `float` to say at least `10^100.`

Thank you.

Comment: I ensure that the input n to this function is always an integer, do not worry about that.

Comment: why don't you use recursive loop for calculating factorial ?

Comment: what is the point in using tail recursive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind about absolute precision, you can use doubles, which can be as large as (approximately) `1.8 * 10^308`.

If precision is of concern, you should use BigDecimal or BigInteger (factorial is an integer function and BigInteger would probably be more efficient than BigDecimal in this case).

Answer (score 4):

you cannot increase the range of any java primitive types as they are set in the JLS.
in your case you can either use double to get more range, or use [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) for arbitrarily-large numbers

Answer (score 2):

Use `double` instead of `float` for extended floating point ranges.

If precision is a concern then you should not use floating point types. Neither `double` nor `float`. Go with [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html). But in this case, also fix your question: `34 != 2.952328229965333E38` is *not* a correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

No need to re-invent the wheel for things as simple as a factorial function.

Use [Google's Guava library](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/README.md). Android apps like **Youtube** and **Google Search** (from Google itself) use Guava.

```
double f = DoubleMath.factorial(n);
```

It accepts input upto n=170, beyond which it returns `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY`.